# example of how to use class -> SingleLaunchActivityTestCase<T extends Activity>

Tags: android, class

I am looking for example of how to use this class:

```
SingleLaunchActivityTestCase<T extends Activity>
```

Till now I am using class InstrumentationTestCase but the problem is that for each launched test case Android calling onSetup() and TearDown()

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of those two classes, it looks like the SingleLaunchActivityTestCase is a wrapper class for InstrumentationTestCase. You should be able to use it the same way as you use InstrumentationTestCase; the only difference is in the constructor.

According to the documentation, you need the package name and the class type of the activity. A typical example of this might be:

```
SingleLaunchActivityTestCase myTestCase;
myTestCase = new SingleLaunchActivityTestCase("com.mycompany.myproject", MyActivity.class);
```